# Failure of a Product using Circular Permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

For the past couple days I've been considering an algebra generated by a set of "units" $ S = \{e_1, \dots, e_n\} $ whose product $ \cdot $ has the following properties.

1. $ e_i \cdot x $ is a circular permutation for all $ x \in S \setminus \{e_i\} $
2. $ (e_i \cdot x) \cdot e_i = x = e_i \cdot (x \cdot e_i) $ for all $ x \in S $.

Finding multiplication tables that satisfy these requirements are very easy for $ n = 3 $

```
* | x y z
--+------
x | x z y
y | z y x
z | y x z
```

and $ n = 4 $

```
* | w x y z
--+--------
w | w z x y
x | y x z w
y | z w y x
z | x y w z
```

But suddenly when $ n = 5 $ it breaks. I haven't been able to find a *nice* proof of this, but because there are only six circular permutations of four elements I was able to show this just by inspection. I also am starting to have my suspicions that it fails for $ n = 6 $ (though I haven't taken a look at all 24 circular permutations yet) and possibly that it fails for $ n \geq 5 $.

Unfortunately, because I haven't found a "nice" proof just from the two assumptions, I don't have any intuition about why it suddenly fails, just that it does. Does anyone have any insights here? The product will be non-associative so that just makes things more annoying to deal with.